# Use Jquery variable to identify a div class/Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure the answer to this is simple, I've just been able to figure it out.

I have a simple click function which applies to any links in a list being clicked. When one is clicked, I want it to remove a class on a div, which is related to one of the links attributes. E.g:

```
// The link
<li><a href="#" title="example1">example1</a></li>

// The div
<div id="example1" class="selected"></div>
```

This is the kinda thing that I've tried, but it aint right:

```
$("ul.switcher a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#" + $(this().val).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated! If anyone could also tell me the JavaScript equivalent of doing this too that would be a nice bonus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you're close:

```
$("ul.switcher a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#" + this.title).removeClass("selected");
});
```

For this sort of thing, the HTML5 "data-" attribute convention can be very handy. You'd change the markup as follows:

```
<li><a href="#" data-targetId="example1">example1</a></li>
```

Then in your code you can use the jQuery ".data()" method:

```
$("ul.switcher a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#" + $(this).data('targetId')).removeClass("selected");
});
```

That technique allows you to avoid "overloading" other attributes, as you've done with "title". (That's not necessarily a bad thing to do, of course, but sometimes you might want the "title" to be something meaningful, since it will after all show up when the mouse is positioned over the element.)

Comment: Knew it would be something simple - thanks for your help! Would 'this.title' also work with standard JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, there's no jQuery in `this.title` - it's important to keep in mind that jQuery **is** JavaScript - it's just a set of functions built on the stock language core, and it doesn't change anything about the ordinary functionality of language constructs.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$("#" + $(this().val).removeClass("selected");
```

to

```
$("#" + this.title).removeClass("selected");
```

That works because the `title` property of the raw DOM object reflects the "title" attribute. Details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-title-attribute) in the draft HTML5 specification, and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-78276800) in the more-established DOM2 HTML specification.

Comment: Can also use the `.text()` assuming it's the same then there's no need for additional attributes or "spamming" the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Call the following javascript function on your link click (used jquery as well),

```
     function removeClass()
     {
        if ( $('#example1').hasClass('selected') ) //Will check whether the div has the mentioned class.
        {
               $('#example1').removeClass('selected'); //This will remove the specified class from the div.
        } 
        else 
        {
          $('#example1').addClass('class1'); //This can be used to add a class to the div.
         }
      }
```

Hope this helps...